# Updating Core Data Model using two separate View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I originally had my app setup to store one line items in a single entity within my core data model. I have since decided to change this to allow the main uitableview to simply list the name of each item and then when you tap on an item you can edit the item name and add additional sub items within a uitextview.

I have two VCs.

- ViewController
- EditItem

I now have two entities.

Item -- > itemName
List -- > listName

`Item` has a relationship to `List`
* list - List - items

`List` has a relationship to `Item`
* items - Item - list

What I am a little confused around is how to go about fetching the data that is being stored in the new entity. If `List` is a child of `Item`, will fetching `Item` automagically fetch objects from `List`?

Right now you are able to input an item on the main VC and save it. If you then tap on that item you are taken to a secondary VC that allows you to edit that item.

When I am fetching `Item` in my main VC, should I also be fetching objects from `List` as well and then pass them within my `prepareforsegue` method?

The idea here is that:

- If the item name exists and it is left alone or edited, it should be written back to the model
- If there is no todolist, the user should add items to the list, and tapping `Save` should update the `item` and the `todo list` at that time.

**current NSFetchedResultsController on ViewController**

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"itemname" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

**current save IBAction on EditItem**

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (self.editItemField) {
    // Update existing device
    self.toDoItem.itemname = self.editItemField.text;
}

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT**

[image: Edit Item VC]
[image: Data Model]

As you can see from the screenshot, the idea is that the top textfield is populated with the list title from the previous VC. This works like it should. The user can then edit the title or leave it as is. They can then add items to that list using the second textfield.

When I submit a list item on the `Edit Item` VC, the new object is saved to my model but is not displayed in the UITableView. From the way I think this should work, I think my Edit Item VC should be setup pretty much like my ViewController VC is setup. I shouldnt have to fetch anything as that is handled initially when I setup my context, etc. Being that there is a relationship between my `Item` entity and my `List` entity, all of that information gets fetched together. Am I correct in that assumption?

When I save an item back to the model on the `Edit Item` VC, is there an association automatically made between the list item and its parent item name?

Any push in the right direction on this is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I added:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    abort();
}
```

Into my viewDidLoad method. This caused the data to actually populate in my UITableView on the EditItem VC however, no matter which Item I tap on in the main VC, I get the same list.

Example:

- I create `Item 1`
- I tap on `Item 1` and then create two items in the EditItem VC
- I go back to the initial VC
- I create `Item 2`
- I tape on `Item 2`
- The same list from `Item 1` is displayed for `Item 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this.

Here is what was done.

First off there was serious cleanup of files, arrangement, etc. There were some objects, attributes, etc., that didnt make sense. Renaming things helped a lot as I was causing a lot of confusion.

There was a one-to-one relationship between my List and my Item entities. This was updated to make it a one-to-many relationship. One list and have many items. Using a predicate to grab just the data that I needed from my model was the key to really fixing the issue.

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"list == %@", self.toDoList];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

Now things work the way they should. Main VC holds many list names. Second VC shows only the items pertaining to that specific list.